# QFileDialog - differences between PyQt4/PyQt5/PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, qfiledialog

I have been working my way through Summerfields book on Rapid GUI programming  with Python and QT (PyQt to be more precise), but the book from 2007 uses version 4.x and I am trying to get going with the current version (5.4.2).

There are some changes that I am trying to figure out and would love some assistance on how to find stuff. Here is an example for a file save dialog - from the book:

```
    fname = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
            "Image Changer - Save Image", fname,
            "Image files ({})".format(" ".join(formats)))
```

This does not work, perhaps primarily because in PyQt5 the `QFileDialog` returns a tuple rather than a string. The only way I can figure this out is just by trial and error. The PyQt5 documentation refers you to QT, which I really do not understand.

I got the following to work:

```
   fname = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'some text',
            "whatever.png", '*.png')
   if "." not in fname[0]:
       fname[0] += ".png"
       self.addRecentFile(fname[0])
       self.filename = fname[0]
       return self.fileSave()
```

Wow, it works! But it is just by slogging through that I get any progress.
I tried running python interpreter and typed:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QFileDialog

help(QFileDialog)
```

This is (sort of) helpful, but the syntax of the help does not make a lot of sense to me, and I do not see what `getSaveFileName` is supposed to return.

What am I missing?

Comment: This could help you: [Reading the Qt Documentation](https://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/a8647.htm). It's just not up to date for signal and slots (function `connect`).

Comment: @tmoreau. That seems to be from a book written in 2001 - for PyQt3.

Answer (score 10):

Some of the static functions of `QFileDialog` have an odd history in PyQt. If you don't know this history, it's hard to make sense of the differences between the various versions of PyQt.

The underlying issue is quite simple. In Python, if a function needs to return more than one value, the most common solution is to return a tuple. But in C++, this is not really possible, so the usual solution is to instead provide arguments that can be modified.

The C++ signature of [`QFileDialog.getSaveFileName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName) is this:

```
getSaveFileName(
    QWidget * parent = 0, const QString & caption = String(),
    const QString & dir = QString(), const QString & filter = QString(),
    QString * selectedFilter = 0, Options options = 0)
```

As you can see, the four `QString` arguments aren't all the same. The first three are `const`, and so won't be modifed by the function, but the `selectedFilter` argument takes a pointer to a `QString`, which means it can be.

Originally, the main use of PyQt was for C++ proto-typing (rather than developing Python applications), and so its APIs were much more faithful to the Qt APIs. This meant that, up until PyQt-4.6, the *only* way to get the selected filter from `QFileDialog`, was to do it the C++ way, like this:

```
>>> s = QString() # string to be modified
>>> f = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, 'Save', '', 'Img(*.png *.jpg)', s)
>>> print s
Img(*.png *.jpg)
```

And in fact, this still works in current versions of PyQt4 (providing it has `QString` enabled, of course).

PyQt4 steadily introduced a lot of changes that have gradually made it more and more Python-friendly over the years - but as the above example shows, this was all done *without* breaking backwards-compatibility. At the time, changing the signature of `getSaveFileName` to return a tuple would have caused far too much breakage, and so functions like `getSaveFileNameAndFilter` were added as a temporary compromise instead.

PyQt5 does not have such restrictions (it doesn't even need to provide `QString` anymore). So it has finally become possible to do the right thing (from a Python point of view) and just return a tuple from `getSaveFileName`. And this principle now applies in general: if you're using PyQt5, and you see a function in the Qt docs that modifies its arguments, you can always expect a tuple to be returned instead.

---

(PS: users of PySide - which is much younger than PyQt - have never had to deal with these issues. For them, the static `QFileDialog` functions have always done the right thing).

Comment: I can't believe this never got any upvotes - this explains perfectly what has been going on and gives me guidance on how to interpret the documentation. Thank you! It's aggravating that if you have no history and you go to the official PyQt5 documentation reference, all that is in QFileDialog is a pointer to the C++ documentation (which of course only returns a QString). Noticing potentially modified arguments is going to be key!

Answer (score 1):

These methods of `QFileDialog` appear to be a bit special because PyQt have implemented their own methods rather than directly wrapping the Qt methods.

Firstly, the PyQt5 `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()` method implements the behaviour of the `QFileDialog.getSaveFileNameAndFilter()` method from PyQt4 ([source](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#qfiledialog)). Secondly, the `QFileDialog.getSaveFileNameAndFilter()` method in PyQt4 returns a tuple of `(filename, selectedFilter)` ([source](http://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/PyQt4/python_v3.html#qfiledialog)).

For reference, the calling signature of the PyQt4 [`QFileDialog.getSaveFileNameAndFilter()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileNameAndFilter) method is

```
getSaveFileNameAndFilter (QWidget parent = None, QString caption = QString(), 
                          QString directory = QString(), QString filter = QString(), 
                          QString initialFilter = QString(), Options options = 0)
```

Hopefully this helps resolve any confusion. Most PyQt5 classes/methods will not be this confusing to decode!

Answer (score 0):

Solving the "tuple issue" of the getSaveFileName method (With PyQt5 ) can be bypassed using this syntax (adding coma and underscore) :

```
fname, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
        "Image Changer - Save Image", fname,
        "Image files ({})".format(" ".join(formats)))
```