# Pressing button in QFileDialog popup exits application

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I made the transition from `PyQt4`to `PyQt5`. My app (created with QtDesigner) has a checkbox which enables a "Save" button, in case you want to save your file. In `PyQt4` the dialog would open, I'd choose my file, press OK, done. I implemented a check on the OK button of the main application that would prompt an error if the path was invalid, e.g. if you pressed cancel in the `QFileDialog`.

With `PyQt5` my application exits completely if I close the `QFileDialog` in any way (OK, cancel, X). I want just the QFileDialog to close and not my main window. How do I do this? Thanks for your time and help.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
self.path = self.ui.savepathButton.pressed.connect(lambda: self.file_save())

def file_save(self):
    path = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Choose a path and filename", os.getcwd().replace("\\", "/") +
                                       "/test.stl", filter="Stereolithography Files (*.stl)")
    self.ui.savepath_label.setText(path) <------ NO ERROR WITHOUT THIS LINE

def OKButton_click(self):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.split(self.ui.savepath_label.text())[0]) is False:
        # Warning if the filename is invalid.
        file_error = QMessageBox()
        file_error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        file_error.setText("Invalid path or filename.")
        file_error.setInformativeText("Please choose a working path and filename.")             file_error.setWindowTitle("File name error")
        file_error.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        file_error.exec_()
    else:
        self.accept()
```

## Edit:

I know where my error is located, but I still cannot fix it. I marked the line in the code. Why does `self.ui.savepath_label.setText(path)` terminate my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PyQt4 provides two different APIs:

- API v1 uses the Qt types for objects, so you have to pass things like `QString` to the `setText` method
- API v2 instead uses python types and the methods of the Qt objects automatically convert those python types into their Qt variants, so you have to pass a python `str` to them.

This is mentioned in [this page](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html) about PyQt4. [PyQt5 only supports version 2 of the API](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#multiple-apis) (that page also mentions other differences).

Also note that according to the question [pyqt5 - finding documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930835/pyqt5-finding-documentation)  the `PyQt5` method `getSaveFileName` actually returns a pair of `(filename, filter)` so it's effectively equivalent to PyQt4's `getSaveFileNameAndFilter` method, which means that you could simply use:

```
self.ui.savepath_label.setText(path[0])
```

To set the text. Minimal complete example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QFileDialog, QWidget, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__(None)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton('click')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.ask_filename)
    def ask_filename(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'title')
        print(fname)
        self.button.setText(fname[0])


app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

By the way, if you change `fname[0]` to `fname` and try to launch this application from the terminal you get the following *helpful* error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_qt.py", line 15, in ask_filename
    self.button.setText(fname)
TypeError: QAbstractButton.setText(str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'
```

which tells you that the return type of `getSaveFileName` is a tuple and not a `str`.

Comment: After I found the workaround with `str()` I noticed, that it would actually return a tuple and basically did what you explained so well in your answer. Thanks for your very insightful post!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the (very small) error:

While `PyQt4` apparently writes the path automatically as `string`, `PyQt5` does not.

I changed

```
self.ui.savepath_label.setText(path)
```

into

```
self.ui.savepath_label.setText(str(path))
```

and all is good now.